# Tornado: don't accept connection

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

This is basic web socket test:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'
        self.write_message("Hello World")

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received %s' % message

    def on_close(self):
      print 'connection closed'


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/ws', WSHandler),
])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I wanted to handle many connections and for some connections I want to accept and others refuse.

Is there any neat way to do it?

Comment: How do you want to decide which to accept?

Comment: like by sending password from clients

Comment: Hi Mero, I have extended my answer to include an example showing authenticate of a socket connection. You might want to edit your question to actually ask that though :)

Answer (score 1):

The `WebSocketHandler` instance has a `request` attribute.

So I would inspect the `self.request` in my `open` method to decide whether or not to immediately close the connection, send an error message, or add the connection to a list for later processing.

Something like:

```
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    connections = []

    def open(self):
        if self.request.remote_ip == '127.0.0.1':
            self.write_message('go away home')
            self.close()
        else:
            self.write_message('welcome')
            self.connections.append(self)
```

You can view the all the attributes available for your inspection by [reading the tornado source Luke](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/httputil.py#L231).

If what you want is to accept or deny connections based on a password then you need to add that logic into the `on_message` method. You also need to maintain a bit of state on the connection. Something like this.

```
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    users = {'dave': 'password1234'}

    def open(self):
        self.authed = False

    def on_message(self, message):
        if self.authed:
            pass # handle already authed messages here
        else:
            # authenticate a connection here
            username, password = message.split(':')
            if self.users.get(username) == password:
                self.authed = True
                self.write_message('Welcome back %s.' % (username,))
            else:
                self.write_message('Auth failed')
```

Please bear in mind that this is not a password protocol that I would ACTUALLY use. It is just an example to show how you might go about creating one.